# differentiate the working of text and attr in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="list">
   <li pid="1">asdf</li>
   <li pid="2">qwer</li>
   <li pid="3">zxcv</li>
</ul>

<script>
$('.list').children('li').text();
</script>
```

return  'asdf qwer zxcv' as expected but

```
<script>
$('.list').children('li').attr('pid');
</script>
```

return only the attribute value of first element '1'.

How to get attribute of all children without using each function

Comment: What is wrong with `each()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.text does not give you an array of texts, but just all the texts in one go:

```js
console.log(
  $(".list li").text()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li pid="1">asdf</li>
  <li pid="2">qwer</li>
  <li pid="3">zxcv</li>
</ul>
```

to get separate attributes use [.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```js
console.log(
  $(".list li").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('pid');
  }).get()
);

// ditto for .text
console.log(
  $(".list li").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li pid="1">asdf</li>
  <li pid="2">qwer</li>
  <li pid="3">zxcv</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No problem @mplungjan . Thanks for your help